# Powershell: Generate unique, random SamAccountName for New-ADUser

Tags: powershell

I've been working the whole day on a PowerShell script for some special customer accounts in our Active directory. These accounts are created following a specific taxonomy that is crucial for some user-mapping between AD and some external applications. We only care for the UPN name (e.g. joe.blogs@domain.com) and couldn't care less for how the 'pre-Windows 2000' account names are formatted.

The issue with the 'pre-Windows 2000' account names however is the limit of 20 characters in length. I thought of simply having it shorted, but this will result in duplicates, which are not allowed (or even possible).

So I was wondering if there is a way that I can generate a random SAM account name. Then the script would check if the account already exists and if so, then would randomize it again until it gets a unique value. Then the account is created using the SAM that has been generated.

What I need help with is with generating the random SAM and checking if an account with such SAM exists. The rest I can handle :)

Is this at all possible? Note that I am just asking on how to go about it -- not for the entire code.

Comment: Make up a prefix, create the accounts like `specifictaxonom00001` and counting up from there. For a new user, `get-aduser -filter "name -like 'specifictaxonom*'"`, expand the name, sort into order, pick the next available one.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thanks. That's what I needed! I can work it from here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a random number generator here in SO some time ago.

```
$chars = [char[]]"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
[string](($chars[0..25]|Get-Random)+(($chars|Get-Random -Count 14) -join ""))
```

chars defines the allowed chars, the second line gets one random uppercase char folllowed by 14 chars from the whole set. Should be easy to add a prefix and test if the name already exists.

Comment: This still can result you in duplicate value. You should always use unique value. Either you can club it with Unique ID or GUID which are unique. Use this for GUID: `[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

I mean if you didn't care about it being characters you could just do random numbers

Example (This theoretically works)

```
$randomNumber = Get-Random 
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $randomNumber -etc...
```